# Error al insertar datos en la base de datos

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando meter datos en la base de datos mediante un formulario, cuando hago meto todos los datos y lo envió me devuelve la página en blanco y no mete los datos ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Formulario:

```html
<!-- Form -->
    <form class="text-center" style="color: #757575;" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">

        <!-- Nombre -->
        <div class="md-form mt-3">
            <input type="text" id="materialContactFormName" class="form-control" name="Nombre">
            <label for="materialContactFormName">Nombre</label>
        </div>
        <!-- Apellidos -->
        <div class="md-form mt-3">
            <input type="text" id="materialContactFormName" class="form-control" name="Apellidos">
            <label for="materialContactFormName">Apellidos</label>
        </div>

        <!-- E-mail -->
        <div class="md-form">
            <input type="email" id="materialContactFormEmail" class="form-control" name="email">
            <label for="materialContactFormEmail">E-mail</label>
        </div>
        <!-- Asunto -->
        <div class="md-form mt-3">
            <input type="text" id="materialContactFormName" class="form-control" name="asunto">
            <label for="materialContactFormName">Asunto</label>
        </div>

        <!--Liga-->
        <p class="text-left">Liga</p>
        <select name="liga" class="browser-default custom-select">
        <option selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
        <option >Monoplazas</option>
        <option >Turismos</option>
        <option >Nascar</option>
        <option >Eventos especiales</option>
        </select>
        <!--/Liga-->
        <br>
        <!--División-->
        <p class="text-left">División</p>
        <select name="division"class="browser-default custom-select">
        <option selected>Selecciona una opción</option>
        <option>Division 1</option>
        <option>Division 2</option>
        <option>Division 3</option>
        </select>
        <!--/División-->
        <!-- Apellidos -->
        <div class="md-form mt-3">
            <input type="text" id="materialContactFormName" class="form-control" name="vuelta">
            <label for="materialContactFormName">Vuelta</label>
        </div>
        <!--Message-->
        <div class="md-form">
            <textarea name="valoracion" type="text" id="materialContactFormMessage" class="form-control md-textarea" rows="3"></textarea>
            <label for="materialContactFormMessage">Tu valoración</label>

        </div>
        <div class="file-field">
    <div class="btn blue-gradient btn-sm float-left">
        <span><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload mr-2" aria-hidden="true"></i>Choose files</span>
        <input type="file" name="archivo" multiple>
    </div>
    <div class="file-path-wrapper">
        <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload one or more files">
    </div>
</div>
        <br>

        <!-- Send button -->
        <button class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-rounded btn-block z-depth-0 my-4 waves-effect" type="submit">Crear</button>

    </form>
```

PHP:

```
    session_start();


$blog_config = array(

    'carpeta_archivos'=>'archivos/'
);


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $nombre = limpiarDatos($_POST['Nombre']);
    $apellidos = limpiarDatos($_POST['Apellidos']);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
    $liga = $_POST['liga'];
    $division = $_POST['division'];
    $vuelta = $_POST['vuelta'];
    $valoracion = $_POST['valoracion'];
  $archivo = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];

  $errores='';

    $archivo_subido = '../' . $blog_config['carpeta_archivos'] . $_FILES['archivo']['name'];

  move_uploaded_file($archivo, $archivo_subido);

  if(empty($nombre) or empty($email) or empty($asunto) or empty($liga) or empty($division) or empty($vuelta) or empty($valoracion) or empty($archivo)){
    $errores='<p class="red-text"> Por favor rellene todos los campos, son obligatorios</p>';

  }else{

    try{
      $conexion= new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=drivers_parade_club', 'root', '');
    }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo"Error:".$e->getMessage();
    }

    if($errores == ''){
      $statement = $conexion->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO remedy (id, Nombre,Apellidos,email,asunto,liga,division,vuelta,valoracion,archivo)
        VALUES (null,:Nombre,:Apellidos,:email,:asunto,:liga,:division,:vuelta,:valoracion,:archivo)'
        );
        $statement->execute(array(
          ':Nombre'=>$nombre,
          ':Apellidos'=>$apellidos,
          ':email'=>$email,
          ':asunto'=>$asunto,
          ':liga'=>$liga,
          ':division'=>$division,
          ':vuelta'=>$vuelta,
          ':valoracion'=>$valoracion,
          ':archivo'=>$$_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name']

      ));
      $resultado = $statement->fetch();
    }

    $errores = '<p class="rex-text"> Se ha creado el ticket correctamente</p>';

  }




    header('Location: home.php');
}
```

Comment: Puedes añadir el error que te sale.

Comment: He dado un var_dump a resultado pero sigue saliendome la pagina en blanco....

Comment: @Flowcou eso que hiciste de colocar solucionado no es correcto

Comment: si ya obtuviste la respuesta a tu pregunta entonces usa la zona de abajo que es para colocar las respuestas, además de explicarla; para que el resto de comunidad la podamos calificar

Comment: Que zona de abajo?

Comment: abajo de la pregunta donde existe un título que dice **TU RESPUESTA** ahi la debes colocar, código y explicación